# using two templates from one view

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to present content from a view in two ways: html and csv download. The only way I was able to do it was to use 2 different views, one for html presentation and one for csv. This duplicates my code and I am looking for a more elegant solution. 
Any suggestions?

Here is the sample code:

```
# views.py

[...]

def member_list(request):
    member_list = Member.objects.all()

    return render_to_response("member_list.html",
                          {'member_list':member_list)


def member_csv_list(request):
    member_list = Member.objects.all()

    csv_list = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    csv_list['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="member_list.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(csv_list)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Member Type', 'Rooms'])
    for member in member_list:
        fields = [member.name, member.member_type, member.room]
        writer.writerow(fields)

    return member_list
```

Comment: your sample codes please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a parameter in your url and implement a view like

```
def myview(request) :

    type = request.GET.get('type', 'html')

    # do processing
    if type == 'html':
        # return html
    else if type == 'csv':
        # return csv
```

If you access a url like `http://yourserver/myview?type=csv` it will render the csv part of the view. When the url `http://yourserver/myview` is accessed it will return the html part of the view.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error using your code: local variable 'type' referenced before assignment. Can you also post the urlconf entry for this option?

Comment: @jcuot, sorry, `type` in `request.GET.get()` should be in quotes. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Rohan's answer is absolutely the right paradigm. For an excellent tutorial-style introduction to this topic, cf. [Multiple Templates in Django](http://www.packtpub.com/article/multiple-templates-in-django).

Here are a few quotes (all credit goes to Scott Newman).

> To serve a printable version of an article, for example, we can add ?printable to the end of the URL.
>
> To make it work, we'll add an extra step in our view to check the URL for this variable. If it exists, we'll load up a printer-friendly template file. If it doesn't exist, we'll load the normal template file.

```
def detail(request, pid):
    '''
    Accepts a press release ID and returns the detail page
    '''
    p = get_object_or_404(PressRelease, id=pid)
    
    if request.GET.has_key('printable'):
        template_file = 'press/detail_printable.html'
    else:
        template_file = 'press/detail.html'

    t = loader.get_template(template_file)
    c = Context({'press': p})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

He continues with *template overrides* and *different templates by domain names*. All this is excellent.