# Serving multiple templates from a single view (or should I use multiple views?)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613843/using-two-templates-from-one-view), I want to populate multiple HTML pages from a single Django view. The difference between this and the link I just mentioned is, I don't want it to be programmatically based. I have links on my template like "Reports" and other company-specific categories. If the user clicks on the Reports link, I want to take them to a new page that will show them the reports. This data is all interrelated, so I initially assumed I would/should be using the same view for all of it. As I started to write this post though, I started wondering if I should in fact use separate views for all of the pages. There shouldn't be more than 3-4 pages total, depending on how I want to split up the categories.

So **TL;DR**: Should I use separate views for each HTML page in my template, or should/could I use a single view to populate all of the various pages on the site, even if most of the data comes from the same sources?

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a base that implements the getContextData with the common stuff and then extend it for each different view

Comment: I agree with this idea ^

Comment: Yes, best approach. That's what class based views are for.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "create a base".. I'm relatively new to the template scene in Django.

Comment: Base class, I think my iPad corrector got in the way again...

Comment: I'll put together an example in 30 mins :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution using class based Views is to create a base view class that will collect the common context data and then extend it as necessary for the specific data and template. Actually the base class does not have to be an extension of `View`, a `ContextMixin`extension is sufficient

The base class should look like this:

```
class BaseContextMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(BaseContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        common_data_1 = ...
        context_data["common_key_1"] = common_data_1
        common_data_2 = ...
        context_data["common_key_2"] = common_data_2
        ...
        return context_data
```

the views then can be implemented as follows:

```
class MyFirstView(TemplateView, BaseContextMixin):
    template_name = "mir/my_first_template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(MyFirstView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data["my_special_key"] = my_special_data
        return context_data

class MySecondView(TemplateView, BaseContextMixin):
    template_name = "mir/my_second_template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(MySecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data["my_special_key_2"] = my_special_data_2
        return context_data
```

This way you avoid redundant code and at the same time you can keep the structure simple

Comment: Superb, I appreciate the example, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: My pleasure. Would love if you could accept the answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using separate views, unless you want to have a similar formatting structure throughout, then maybe you would just use one view. Even then, though, you can use separate views with a similar HTML structure. It really depends on how you want your documents structured.